# React Admin - ReferenceInput with multiple fields output

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, json-server

I'm using React with React Admin to populate my database in which I have 2 collections: `products` and `stores`

I need to link a store to the product, so normally I should do:

```js
<ReferenceInput label="Store" source="storeId" reference="stores">
  <SelectInput optionText="name" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

But this will generate this structure:

```js
{
  id: '...'
  // other attributes
  storeId: "choosed-store-id"
}
```

But the final result I need is something like this:

```js
{
  id: '...'
  // other attributes
  store: {
    id: "choosed-store-id",
    name: "choosed-store-name",
    address: "choosed-store-address"
  }
}
```